# Multiple variable assignment

Tags: go

The below code snippet confused me:

`v, ok := a[1] // error: assignment count mismatch: 2 = 1`

The above code throws an error because of count mismatch, but the below code snippet seems to work fine:

```
for i, id:= range ids
{
   fmt.Printf("%d - ID: %d\n",i,id)
}
```

Does this mean that the `range` returns both the index and the value due to which the code snippet above works fine?

Comment: Yes https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_range

Comment: Note also that the "comma ok" idiom, which is a special form of assignment is supported only by 3 expressions, [type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions), [channel receives](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator), and [map indexing](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions). Slice indexing does not support that special form which is why you've got that error.

Comment: Yeah, but again this would work if you finding in a map.
If in an array this is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

The `range` form of the for loop iterates over a slice or map.

When ranging over a slice, two values are returned for each iteration:

1. The first is the index of the slice;
2. The second is a copy of the element at that index.

Let's assume that we have a function that verify if a number is a `prime number`, and we have an array with the candidate numbers, than we can call the function in two different way:

```golang
var prime []int = []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23}

func TestIsPrimeByValue(t *testing.T) {
    for _, item := range prime {
        if !IsPrime(item) {
            t.Fail()
        }
    }
}

func TestIsPrimeByIndex(t *testing.T) {
    for i := range prime {
        if !IsPrime(prime[i]) {
            t.Fail()
        }
    }
}
```

With the first loop, we are iterating the `value` of the array.
With the second loop, we are iterating the `index` of the array.